# Printing plain underscores in file names

Tags: verbatim, auxiliary-files, includegraphics, missing, underscore

I would like to display the filename when an `\includegraphics` command refers to a missing file (without producing errors).
Currently it doesn't work for files with an underscore in the file name.

Note that I cannot change the underscores in the reference to the files into something like `\_` because the backslash is not in the actual filename.

I've tried using verbatim, but I cannot get that to work.

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}


    \newcommand{\noimage}[1]{%
      \setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}%
      \fbox{\phantom{\rule{10pt}{10pt}} Missing file: #1 \phantom{\rule{10pt}{10pt}}}% Framed box
    }
    \let\includegraphicsoriginal\includegraphics
    \renewcommand{\includegraphics}[2][width=\textwidth]{\IfFileExists{#2}{\includegraphicsoriginal[#1]{#2}}{\noimage{#2}}}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics{example_file.pdf}

\end{document}
```

If the file is missing the required output would be something like the following; otherwise it would be the actual image.

[image: missing_graphics]

Comment: I normally use the `\path` command from the `url` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I normally do

Either use `\path` from `url` or use detokenize and remember fontenc

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \newcommand{\noimage}[1]{%
      \setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}%
      \fbox{\phantom{\rule{10pt}{10pt}} Missing file:
        % \expandafter\path\expandafter{#1}
        \detokenize{#1}
        \phantom{\rule{10pt}{10pt}}}% Framed box
    }
    \let\includegraphicsoriginal\includegraphics
    \renewcommand{\includegraphics}[2][width=\textwidth]{\IfFileExists{#2}{\includegraphicsoriginal[#1]{#2}}{\noimage{#2}}}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics{example_file.pdf}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What would be the difference between using the `\path` method and the `\detokenize` method? Why choose one over the other?

Comment: In this case, not much difference. In other circumstances `\path` can line break at a `_` for example.